# SSL on primary subdomain not showing securely

Tags: ssl

Hoping this doesn't come across as a stupid question. Server and SSL stuff isn't my forte.

I've got a wildcard SSL cert and on my root domain it works. On one of my subdomains it show securely. But on a second subdomain I get the broken padlock.

```
www.mydomain.ca - secure
www.subdom.mydomain.ca - secure
www.subdom2.mydomain.ca - broken padlock
```

Now with the root domain I know its a particular CMS, the first subdom is a Drupal site and the one that is broken right now is hosted in Azure.

I suppose my question is do I need to install a seperate SSL cert on my subdom2? (For all I know it was done to the first subdom before my time). Or is the nature of a wildcard SSL cert to cover anything that's a subdomain - provided that all the content is being served securely on the website?

**Update**

If anyone comes across this, the issue was our vendor was serving an image that wasn't https. In the end in the issue had nothing to do with my wildcard SSL cert and it looks as though it does in fact cover all subdomains as long as content is being served securely!

Comment: Is your sub-domain URL really like `www.subdom.mydomain.ca`, with the "www."? All wildcard certificates I've come across only allow a single level of wildcard, at the front, so "*.mydomain.ca" would cover "subdom.mydomain.ca", but not "www.subdom.mydomain.ca".

Comment: Meanwhile, the convention on this site is that Questions and Answers are always kept separate, so if you have solved your own problem, [you are encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead of editing the solution into the question. That way the question is automatically marked as "answered", and it's clearer to future readers.

Comment: @IMSoP fair callout! Made my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, the issue was our vendor was serving an image that wasn't https. In the end in the issue had nothing to do with my wildcard SSL cert and it looks as though it does in fact cover all subdomains as long as content is being served securely!